# Login auth in Laravel without using database

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Im somewhat new to laravel, i need to set an user/password login system, but i cannot use the default database. Is possible to store the information credentials other than in a database? What would an example look like?

Comment: Store your  login credentials on your cache memory

Answer (score -1):

Laravel's Authentication System relies on Eloquent and therefore on a database. With [Sushi](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi) you can use an Array as your database driver. 
Maybe this would be an approach which could work for you.

Another idea could be to use [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). You can set this up in your webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc.) or in Laravel with a Middleware.

Here's how such a middleware could look like.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BasicAuthMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $authenticationHasPassed = false;

        if ($request->header('PHP_AUTH_USER', null) && $request->header('PHP_AUTH_PW', null)) {
            $username = $request->header('PHP_AUTH_USER');
            $password = $request->header('PHP_AUTH_PW');

            if ($username === config('auth.basic_auth.username') && $password === config('auth.basic_auth.password')) {
                $authenticationHasPassed = true;
            }
        }

        if ($authenticationHasPassed === false) {
            return response()->make('Invalid credentials.', 401, ['WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

(This code example is from [a blog post](https://stefanzweifel.io/posts/use-basic-authentication-to-protect-the-laravel-horizon-dashboard/) of mine, where I needed an authentication feature without using a database).

I recommend reading the documentation about [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#introduction) and [Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#introduction) if you want to implement this.

Comment: thx for the answer, just asking but using basic auth where i would store the credentials? i need to set it so i can register users and validate the credentials against that

Comment: @Mashyu and where are you going to store these credentials?

Comment: @Mashyu Well, you could store the credentials in a environment variable in your .env file. But you would have to update the file manually, but that won't scale really well.

You write you can't use the default database. I would suggest adding a second database connection and using that connection on your `User`-model, if you don't want to add credentials manually.